# Nodejs debugger pause thread

Tags: node.js, concurrency, nonblocking, node-debugger

Suppose if there is one request `R1` being processed by the **Nodejs server** and the ***debugger has paused the system*** at a *breakpoint*.

Now at this point (after pause) if another request `R2` is made by the client, does it enter the Nodejs server at all?

**If it doesn't enter the server**, then which component of Nodejs server will keep that request R2 on standby till that debugger pause is released?

**If it does enter the server**, then which component of Nodejs server will handle this R2 and how?

I can't find anything on this, any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I don't think there's a definitive answer for that. does the debugger just stops the JS thread or all the threads? and also, is this server clustered? it depends

Answer (score 1):

> If it doesn't enter the server, then which component of Nodejs server
>   will keep that request R2 on standby till that debugger pause is
>   released?

**I GUESS** : The request would simply timeout, without guetting any response. (HTTP layer). If you have something like nginx in front of node, it would be a 502 serve by nginx, because it can have response from your node backend.

> If it does enter the server, then which component of Nodejs server
>   will handle this R2 and how?

The poll queue.

The best info you can get on the way node is functionning internaly, event loop etc.., is here : https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/topics/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick.md

Take a look it's worth the time.

Comment: Thanks for the link, will go through it.